# Перестала работать строка поиска suggestview , хелп

Tags: yandex-maps-api

[image: Перестала работать строка поиска suggestview , хелп]

Перестала работать строка поиска suggestview, на скрине базовай пример с яндекс на пустой стр ,тоже самое, кто знает в чем дело?

Answer (score 0):

Теперь все обращения к **[Геосаджесту](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geosuggest/)** требуют ключа от этого сервиса, включая все подсказки в **JavaScript API** (*SuggestView, поисковая строка, панель маршрутов*). Подробней это описано на [страницах используемых методов](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/suggest).

**Чтобы использовать саджест в JS API**:

1. Получите ключ для саджеста через личный кабинет.
2. Укажите его при подключении JS API в формате `https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&apikey=<ваш ключ для JS API>&suggest_apikey=<ваш ключ для Suggest API>`.

Угловые скобки вокруг полученного в [кабинете разработчика](https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/) ключа оставлять не надо.