# Яндекс.Карты API проблема с Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: yandex-maps-api, access-control

При использовании API Яндекс.Карт на сайте, при вводе адреса доставки и выбора предлагаемого адреса из SuggestView возникает ошибка `has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Ошибка возникает не всегда, но причину её возникновения я, к сожалению, не смог понять.
Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобным и знает что можно сделать для её решения?

Comment: Получите в кабинете разработчика и добавьте в вызов API ключ Геосаджеста. Без ключа ошибка CORS также вылазит регулярно.
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1543170/386299